# Solidworks VBA macro: change color of selected faces

Tags: vba, solidworks

I am working on a solidworks macro of which one of the functions is to change the color of the selected faces.  Unfortunately, the example provided in the [documentation](https://help.solidworks.com/2015/English/api/sldworksapi/Change_Color_of_Face_Example_VB.htm?verRedirect=1) only colors one selected face; I need to change the color of all selected faces.

Here is the sub I was working on:

```
    Sub color(R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer)
    Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr
    Dim swFace As SldWorks.Face2
    Dim vFaceProp As Variant
    Dim bRet As Boolean
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager
    Set swFace = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject6(1, -1)
    vFaceProp = swFace.MaterialPropertyValues
    If IsEmpty(vFaceProp) Then
        ' Is empty if face-level colors were not specified,
        ' so get them from underlying model
        vFaceProp = swModel.MaterialPropertyValues
    End If
    'Current color
    Debug.Print "RGB            = [" & vFaceProp(0) * 255# & ", " & vFaceProp(1) * 255# & ", " & vFaceProp(2) * 255# & "]"
    Debug.Print "Ambient        = " & vFaceProp(3)
    Debug.Print "Diffuse        = " & vFaceProp(4)
    Debug.Print "Specular       = " & vFaceProp(5)
    Debug.Print "Shininess      = " & vFaceProp(6)
    Debug.Print "Transparency   = " & vFaceProp(7)
    Debug.Print "Emission       = " & vFaceProp(8)
    ' New color
    bRet = swModel.SelectedFaceProperties(RGB(R, G, B), vFaceProp(3), vFaceProp(4), vFaceProp(5), vFaceProp(6), vFaceProp(7), vFaceProp(8), False, "")
    
    ' Deselect face to see new color
    swModel.ClearSelection2 True
End Sub
```

Edit: Solved my issue: This is for SolidWorks 2015.

```
    Sub color(R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer)

    Dim swApp                       As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel                     As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swSelMgr                    As SldWorks.SelectionMgr
    Dim swFace                      As SldWorks.Face2
    Dim bRet                        As Boolean
    Dim PocPloch                    As Integer
    Dim i                           As Long
    Dim color As Integer

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
    Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
    Set swSelMgr = swModel.SelectionManager
   
    PocPloch = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectCount 'nuber of selected faces

    For i = PocPloch To 1 Step -1
        Set swFace = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObject(i) 'get the last selected face
        'Sets the colour of last selected face
        swModel.SelectedFaceProperties GetHexFromRGB(R, G, B), 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.315, 0, 0, 0, ""
        bRet = swFace.DeSelect 'deselect last face
    Next i

End Sub
```

Will need this GetHexFromRGB function to convert the RGB value to Hex

```
Function GetHexFromRGB(R As Integer, G As Integer, B As Integer) As String
'For some reason this has to be in BGR order instead of RGB
GetHexFromRGB = "&H" & VBA.Right$("" & VBA.Hex(B), 2) & _
    VBA.Right$("00" & VBA.Hex(G), 2) & VBA.Right$("00" & VBA.Hex(R), 2)

End Function
```

Comment: https://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapi/get_selected_faces_on_process_body_example_vb.htm shows how to access all selected faces.

Comment: Thanks, I'll muck around with it and report back if I figure anything out.  I'm using SW 2015 by the way, but there is also an example for 2015.